# queue.Queue vs. collections.deque

Tags: python, queue, thread-safety, python-multithreading, deque

I need a queue which multiple threads can put stuff into, and multiple threads may read from.

Python has at least two queue classes, `queue.Queue` and `collections.deque`, with the former seemingly using the latter internally. Both claim to be thread-safe in the documentation.

However, the `Queue` docs also state:

> `collections.deque` is an alternative
> implementation of unbounded queues
> with fast atomic `append()` and
> `popleft()` operations **that do not
> require locking** and also support indexing.

Which I guess I don't quite understand: Does this mean `deque` isn't fully thread-safe after all?

If it is, I may not fully understand the difference between the two classes. I can see that `Queue` adds blocking functionality. On the other hand, it loses some `deque` features like support for the `in` operator.

Is accessing the [internal `deque` object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0e2d67457ba245442457432d15115d1dc1b0ecb5/Lib/queue.py#L207) directly

```py
x in Queue().queue
```

thread-safe?

Also, why does `Queue` employ a mutex for its operations when `deque` is thread-safe already?

Comment: `RuntimeError: deque mutated during iteration` is what you could be getting is using a shared `deque` between several thread and no locking...

Comment: @toine that doesn't have anything to do with threads though. You can get this error whenever you add/delete to a `deque` while iterating even in the same thread. The only reason you can't get this error from `Queue` is that `Queue` doesn't support iteration.

Comment: If you have the book "Effective Python", there's a really nice comparison of Queue vs deque in a multi-threaded use case in Item 55 ("Use Queue to Coordinate Work Between Threads").

Answer (score 409, accepted):

`queue.Queue` and `collections.deque` serve different purposes. `queue.Queue` is intended for allowing different threads to communicate using queued messages/data, whereas `collections.deque` is simply intended as a data structure. That's why `queue.Queue` has methods like `put_nowait()`, `get_nowait()`, and `join()`, whereas `collections.deque` doesn't. `queue.Queue` isn't intended to be used as a collection, which is why it lacks the likes of the `in` operator.

It boils down to this: if you have multiple threads and you want them to be able to communicate without the need for locks, you're looking for `queue.Queue`; if you just want a queue or a double-ended queue as a datastructure, use `collections.deque`.

Finally, accessing and manipulating the internal deque of a `queue.Queue` is playing with fire - you really don't want to be doing that.

Comment: If you need a thread-safe queue and performance is important, `deque` seems a better option than `Queue`: see Jonathan's answer. Plus with `deque` you get list-like flexibility and visibility as a bonus, although that is not all thread-safe.

Comment: No, that's not a good idea at all. If you look at the source of `Queue.Queue`, it uses `deque` under the hood. `collections.deque` is a collection, while `Queue.Queue` is a communications mechanism. The overhead in `Queue.Queue` is to make it threadsafe. Using `deque` for communicating between threads will only lead to painful races. Whenever `deque` happens to be threadsafe, that's a happy accident of how the interpreter is implemented, and *not* something to be relied upon. That's why `Queue.Queue` exists in the first place.

Comment: The docs say `deque` is thread-safe for pops and appends, which are all you need for a simple queue, perhaps wrapping `pop`s with a `try: except IndexError` for when it's empty. Some interpreters disobey this? It's true I stick with cpython. I use `deque` myself because `Queue` is way too slow for my purposes. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects

Comment: Just keep in mind that if you're communicating across threads, you're playing with fire by using deque. deque is threadsafe *by accident* due to the existence of the GIL. An GIL-less implementation will have completely different performance characteristics, so discounting other implementations isn't wise. Besides, have you timed Queue vs deque for use across threads as opposed to a naive benchmark of its use in a single thread? If your code is *that* sensitive to the speed of Queue vs deque, Python might not be the language you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. Yes, my benchmarks are across threads. True python isn't the fastest language but I use it because of `pandas`.

Comment: @KeithGaughan `deque is threadsafe by accident due to the existence of GIL`; it is true that `deque` relies on GIL to ensure thread-safety - but it's not `by accident`. The official python documentation clearly states that `deque` `pop*`/`append*` methods are thread-safe. So any valid python implementation must provide the same guarantee (GIL-less implementations will have to figure out how to do that without GIL). You can safely rely on those guarantees.

Comment: @fantabolous my previous comment notwithstanding, I don't quite understand how you would use `deque` for communication. If you wrap `pop` into a `try/except`, you will end up with a busy loop eating up enormous amount of CPU just waiting for new data. This seems like a horribly inefficient approach compared to the blocking calls offered by `Queue`, which ensure that the thread waiting for data will go to sleep and not waste CPU time.

Comment: You might want to take a read of the source code for `Queue.Queue` then, because it's written using `collections.deque`: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/Queue.py - it uses condition variables to efficiently allow the `deque` it wraps to be accessed over thread boundaries safely and efficiently. The explanation of how you'd use a `deque` for communication is right there in the source.

Comment: brian-brazil and @KeithGaughan both of your answers contradict each other as well as the python documentation. The doc I'm reading says both are thread safe. So who is right in this case?

Comment: `collections.deque` is _technically_ threadsafe, but only on CPython due to how the GIL works, and even then it's not _guaranteed_ to be so. `queue.Queue` (because Python 3 exists now) is _guaranteed_ to be threadsafe. If you want a threadsafe queue, you use the latter. To quote the docs: "It is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be exchanged safely between multiple threads." There's no debate here.

Answer (score 63):

If all you're looking for is **a thread-safe way to transfer objects between threads**, then both would work (both for FIFO and LIFO). For FIFO:

- [`Queue.put()` and `Queue.get()` are thread-safe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#)
- [`deque.append()` and `deque.popleft()` are thread-safe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects)

Note:

- Other operations on `deque` might not be thread safe, I'm not sure.
- `deque` does not block on `pop()` or `popleft()` so you can't base your consumer thread flow on blocking till a new item arrives.

However, it seems that **deque has a significant efficiency advantage**. Here are some benchmark results in seconds using CPython 2.7.3 for inserting and removing 100k items

```
deque 0.0747888759791
Queue 1.60079066852
```

Here's the benchmark code:

```
import time
import Queue
import collections

q = collections.deque()
t0 = time.clock()
for i in xrange(100000):
    q.append(1)
for i in xrange(100000):
    q.popleft()
print 'deque', time.clock() - t0

q = Queue.Queue(200000)
t0 = time.clock()
for i in xrange(100000):
    q.put(1)
for i in xrange(100000):
    q.get()
print 'Queue', time.clock() - t0
```

Comment: You claim that "Other operations on `deque` may not be thread safe". Where do you get that from?

Comment: @Matt - rephrased to better convey my meaning

Comment: Ok, thanks. That was stopping me from using deque because I thought you knew something I didn't. I guess I'll just assume it's thread safe until I discover otherwise.

Comment: @Matt "The deque's append(), appendleft(), pop(), popleft(), and len(d) operations are thread-safe in CPython." source: https://bugs.python.org/issue15329

Comment: The docs for new versions of both Python 2 and 3 state that "Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in either direction."

Comment: # python 3 
# deque 0.0154882
# Queue 0.4530072
# deque 0.0149755
# LifoQueue 0.350331
import time
import queue
import collections

##### Queue (FIFO) Test ######
q = collections.deque()
t0 = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(100000):
    q.append(1)
for i in range(100000):
    q.popleft()
print ('deque', time.perf_counter() - t0)

q = queue.Queue(200000)
t0 = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(100000):
    q.put(1)
for i in range(100000):
    q.get()
print( 'Queue', time.perf_counter() - t0)

Answer (score 13):

For information there is a Python ticket referenced for deque thread-safety (https://bugs.python.org/issue15329).
Title "clarify which deque methods are thread-safe"

Bottom line here: https://bugs.python.org/issue15329#msg199368

> The deque's append(), appendleft(), pop(), popleft(), and len(d)
>   operations are thread-safe in CPython.   The append methods have a
>   DECREF at the end (for cases where maxlen has been set), but this
>   happens after all of the structure updates have been made and the
>   invariants have been restored, so it is okay to treat these operations
>   as atomic.

Anyway, if you are not 100% sure and you prefer reliability over performance, just put a like Lock ;)

Answer (score 11):

All single-element methods on `deque` are atomic and thread-safe. All other methods are thread-safe too. Things like `len(dq)`, `dq[4]` yield momentary correct values. But think e.g. about `dq.extend(mylist)`: you don't get a guarantee that all elements in `mylist` are filed in a row when other threads also append elements on the same side - but thats usually not a requirement in inter-thread communication and for the questioned task.

So a `deque` is ~20x faster than `Queue` (which uses a `deque` under the hood) and unless you don't need the "comfortable" synchronization API (blocking / timeout), the strict `maxsize` obeyance or the *"Override these methods (_put, _get, ..)  to implement other queue organizations"* sub-classing behavior, or when you take care of such things yourself, then a bare `deque` is a good and efficient deal for high-speed inter-thread communication.

In fact the heavy usage of an extra mutex and extra method `._get()` etc. method calls in `Queue.py` is due to backwards compatibility constraints, past over-design and lack of care for providing an efficient solution for this important speed bottleneck issue in inter-thread communication. A list was used in older Python versions - but even list.append()/.pop(0)  was & is atomic and threadsafe ...

Comment: Could you post source of your information that list or deque is thread-safe?

Answer (score 6):

Adding `notify_all()` to each `deque` `append` and `popleft` results in far worse results for `deque` than [the 20x improvement achieved by default `deque` behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20330499/3427777):

```
deque + notify_all: 0.469802
Queue:              0.667279
```

@Jonathan modify his code a little and I get the benchmark using cPython 3.6.2 and add condition in deque loop to simulate the behaviour Queue do.

```
import time
from queue import Queue
import threading
import collections

mutex = threading.Lock()
condition = threading.Condition(mutex)
q = collections.deque()
t0 = time.clock()
for i in range(100000):
    with condition:
        q.append(1)
        condition.notify_all()
for _ in range(100000):
    with condition:
        q.popleft()
        condition.notify_all()
print('deque', time.clock() - t0)

q = Queue(200000)
t0 = time.clock()
for _ in range(100000):
    q.put(1)
for _ in range(100000):
    q.get()
print('Queue', time.clock() - t0)
```

And it seems the performance limited by 
this function `condition.notify_all()`

> collections.deque is an alternative implementation of unbounded queues with fast atomic append() and popleft() operations that do not require locking.
>   [docs Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)

Answer (score 2):

`deque` is thread-safe. "operations that do not require locking" means that you don't have to do the locking yourself, the `deque` takes care of it.

Taking a look at the `Queue` source, the internal deque is called `self.queue` and uses a mutex for accessors and mutations, so `Queue().queue` is *not* thread-safe to use.

If you're looking for an "in" operator, then a deque or queue is possibly not the most appropriate data structure for your problem.

Comment: Well, what I want to do is make sure that no duplicates are added to the queue. Is this not something a queue could potentially support?

Comment: It'd probably be best to have a separate set, and update that when you add/remove something from the queue. That'll be O(log n) rather than O(n), but you'll have to be careful to keep the set and queue in sync (i.e. locking).

Comment: A Python set is a hash table, so it would be O(1).  But yes, you would still have to do locking.

Comment: @brian-brazil and KeithGaughan both of your answers contradict each other as well as the python documentation. The doc I'm reading says both are thread safe. So who is right in this case?

Answer (score 1):

(seems I don't have reputation to comment...)
You need to be careful which methods of the deque you use from different threads.

deque.get() appears to be threadsafe, but I have found that doing

```
for item in a_deque:
   process(item)
```

can fail if another thread is adding items at the same time.
I got an RuntimeException that complained "deque mutated during iteration".

Check [collectionsmodule.c](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c) to see which operations are affected by this

Comment: this kind of error is not special for threads and principal thread-safety. It happens e.g. by just  doing  `>>> di = {1:None}
>>> for x in di: del di[x]`

Comment: Basically you should never loop over something that might be modified by another thread (although in some cases you could do it by adding your own protection). Like a Queue, you're intended to pop/get an item off the queue before processing it, and you would normally do that with a `while` loop.