# Why is using deque of Queue.Queue considered dangerous?

Tags: python, queue

In a program where I store some `dict` in a `Queue.Queue` and I have to list each entry without removing them from the queue. Now I use this code snippet to iterate over the entries:

```
elements = Queue.Queue()
# populate the queue

for elem in list(elements.queue):
    # print elem
```

In the code of `Lib/Queue.py` and `Lib/collections.py` I found that `queue` is a proxy to `deque` and in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/717261/1157147) of "Python: Queue.Queue vs. collections.deque" is mentioned not to use `deque` directly.

Is there any particular reason not to use `deque`? Hope someone can elaborate a little bit.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the answer. There's nothing wrong with using `collections.deque`, you just don't want to use `Queue.deque` when using a `Queue` object. That is the internal deque of the `Queue` object, and you shouldn't directly manipulate it.

Comment: The explanation is fairly clear in the question you linked to... If you just need a data structure then a deque is fine.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason its dangerous to iterate over the internal `deque` of a `Queue.Queue` is that another thread could come along and add or remove items from the `deque` while you're iterating over it (by using `queue.put`/`queue.get`). This means that your iterable could change size during iteration, which causes undefined behavior in Python, and is not something you want to happen. You *can* iterate over the `deque` safely, though, by acquiring the internal `mutex` of the `Queue` first:

```
elements = Queue.Queue()
# populate the queue

with elements.mutex:
    for elem in list(elements.queue):
        # print elem
```

This way, all other threads will be prevented from adding or removing elements from the `Queue` while you iterate.

Now, this has nothing to do with using `deque` in general - which is a perfectly valid thing to do. It's just within the context of using the `deque` that's internal to a `Queue.Queue` that you need to be careful.