# Python Interactive brokers IB API very very slow

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

I am trying out the new Python Interactive Broker API, but I am experiencing some serious speed issues at the very first step...

The following code  (see below) times

`0:00:08.832813` until the data is done being received

`0:00:36.000785` until the app is fully disconnected...

Why is it so slow?
What would be the best way to speed it up?

```
from ibapi import wrapper
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.utils import iswrapper #just for decorator
from ibapi.common import *
from ibapi.contract import *
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta


class DataApp(wrapper.EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        wrapper.EWrapper.__init__(self)
        EClient.__init__(self, wrapper=self)

    @iswrapper
    def historicalData(self, reqId: TickerId, date: str, open: float, high: float,
                            low: float, close: float, volume: int, barCount: int,
                            WAP: float, hasGaps: int):
        super().historicalData(reqId, date, open, high, low, close, volume,
                                barCount, WAP, hasGaps)
        print("HistoricalData. ", reqId, " Date:", date, "Open:", open,
               "High:", high, "Low:", low, "Close:", close, "Volume:", volume)

    @iswrapper
    def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId: int, start: str, end: str):
        super().historicalDataEnd(reqId, start, end)
        print("HistoricalDataEnd ", reqId, "from", start, "to", end)
        print(datetime.datetime.now()-startime)
        self.done = True # This ends the messages loop - this was not in the example code...

    def get_data(self):        
        self.connect("127.0.0.1", 4002, clientId=10)
        print("serverVersion:%s connectionTime:%s" % (self.serverVersion(),
                                                self.twsConnectionTime()))

        cont = Contract()
        cont.symbol = "ES"
        cont.secType = "FUT"
        cont.currency = "USD"
        cont.exchange = "GLOBEX"
        cont.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "201706"
        self.reqHistoricalData(1, cont, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"),
                               "1800 S", "30 mins", "TRADES", 0, 1, [])
        self.run()        
        self.disconnect()
        print(datetime.datetime.now()-startime)

global starttime
startime = datetime.datetime.now()
DA = DataApp()
DA.get_data()
```

I also tried to continually run it is the background, in order to only submit requests on the fly with

```
def runMe():
    app.run() # where run() has be removed from the class definition

import threading
thread = threading.Thread(target = runMe)
thread.start()
```

But it was also incredibly slow.
Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you modify the connection socket lock within the connection class in the ibapi module.  The recommendation came from heshiming on github; if you have access to the private interactive brokers repo you can access the discussion here https://github.com/InteractiveBrokers/tws-api/issues/464

I did this and it improved performance significantly.

Heshiming recommends you reduce the timeout on the socket lock object, which is called every time you send or receive a message. 
To modify the socket lock, Go to the site-packages folder for ibapi and modify the connect function within connection.py, changing "self.socket.settimeout(1)" to "self.socket.settimeout(0.01)". This is line 48 in connection.py for the version I have.

In case you can't see heshiming's post, I've included it at the bottom of this post.

Alternative Option: another interesting solution would be to leverage asyncio for an asynchronous event loop. I have not done this but it looks promising. See the example Ewald put together https://github.com/erdewit/tws_async

Heshiming Comment:

> The implementation of Connection /ibapi/connection.py
>   has a Lock object shared in both sendMsg and recvMsg. Since connect,
>   self.socket.settimeout(1) is called, therefore the underlying
>   self.socket.recv(4096) only times out once per second.
>
> Such implementation creates a performance problem. Since the lock is
>   shared, the socket cannot send data while receiving. In the scenario
>   where the message received is less than 4k bytes long, the recvMsg
>   function will wait for 1 second before releasing the lock, making
>   subsequent sendMsg wait. In my experiment, most messages appear to be
>   shorter than 4k bytes. In other words, this imposes a cap of one
>   recvMsg per second.
>
> There are couple strategies to mitigate this. One can reduce the
>   receive buffer to a number much less than 4k, or reduce the socket
>   timeout to something like 0.001 second to make it block less.
>
> Or according to
>   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981372/are-parallel-calls-to-send-recv-on-the-same-socket-valid
>   , the socket itself is actually thread-safe. Thus no locks are
>   necessary.
>
> I tried all three strategies. Removing the lock works the best. And
>   reducing the timeout to 0.001 works in similar ways.
>
> I can only vouch for linux/unix platforms, and I haven't tried it on
>   Windows. Would you consider to change the implementation to improve
>   this?

Comment: The latest version of the api (May 2019) no longer has a lock in `recvMsg`; it's only used in `sendMsg` which seems reasonable. The timeout is still 1s but absent the lock that shouldn't cause issues considering that `sendMsg` and `recvMsg` would typically be running in different threads.

Answer (score 0):

The current API (May 2019) has improved speed by removing the lock in `recvMsg` as @BenM proposed in his answer. However, it can still be slow depending on the type of request.

**Removing most of their logging** helped, presumably because some msg types are quite large. I initially tried filtering it out using the `logging` library, but flat-out removing the code worked better speed-wise, and I put this down to the extra processing required to generate the larger strings before even being passed to `logging`.

**Replace Queue with deque**: It might also be worth replacing the `Queue` in `client.py` with a [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects) because `deque` is >10x faster. I've done this elsewhere for big speed ups but haven't gotten to it yet for this. `deque` should be thread-safe without locks the way it would be used here: "Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque" (from the docs).

[Queue vs deque speed comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20330499/3427777)

Answer (score -1):

`app.run()` is an infinite loop while `app.done == False`, but it do not stop immediately when `app.done` is set to True. (I don't know why).

What I have done is to write a new method instead of using `app.run()`.

Here's my solution:

```
import time
from ibapi import (decoder, reader, comm)
```

and put this function into your Client Class.

```
def getMessage(self, wait=3):
    # wait 3 secs for response to come in
    time.sleep(wait)
    # get everything in app.msg_queue
    while not self.msg_queue.empty():
        text = self.msg_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.2)
        fields = comm.read_fields(text)
        self.decoder.interpret(fields)
```

the usage is simple. Just use `app.getMessage()` instead of `app.run()`

Comment: This exits as soon as the queue is empty, so would require you to keep calling it in presumably an infinite loop.