# Is the rear item in a Queue the last item added or the item at the end of a Queue?

Tags: python-3.x, queue

My professor wrote a Queue class that uses arrays. I was giving it multiple test cases and got confused with one specific part. I want to figure out if the last item added is the rear of the queue. Lets say I enqueued 8 elements:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Then I dequeued. And now:

```
[None, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I enqueued 9 onto the Queue and it goes to the front. However, when I called my method that returns the rear item of the queue, q.que_rear, it returned 8. I thought the rear item would be 9? Since it was the last item added.

Here is how I tested it in case anyone is confused:

```
>>> q = ArrayQueue()
>>> q.enqueue(1)
>>> q.enqueue(2)
>>> q.enqueue(3)
>>> q.enqueue(4)
>>> q.data
[1, 2, 3, 4, None, None, None, None]
>>> q.dequeue()
1
>>> q.enqueue(5)
>>> q.enqueue(6)
>>> q.enqueue(7)
>>> q.enqueue(8)
>>> q.data
[None, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> q.enqueue(9)
>>> q.data
[9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> q.que_rear()
Rear item is 8
```

***EDIT***
I just want to know what’s supposed to be the “rear of the Queue”? The last element added, or the element at the end of the list? In this case I showed, is it supposed to be 8 or 9?

Here is my code:

```
class ArrayQueue:
    INITIAL_CAPACITY = 8
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [None] * ArrayQueue.INITIAL_CAPACITY
        self.rear = ArrayQueue.INITIAL_CAPACITY -1
        self.num_of_elems = 0
        self.front_ind = None

    # O(1) time
    def __len__(self):
        return self.num_of_elems

    # O(1) time
    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self) == 0

    # Amortized worst case running time is O(1)
    def enqueue(self, elem):
        if self.num_of_elems == len(self.data):
            self.resize(2 * len(self.data))

        if self.is_empty():
            self.data[0] = elem
            self.front_ind = 0
            self.num_of_elems += 1
        else:
            back_ind = (self.front_ind + self.num_of_elems) % len(self.data)
            self.data[back_ind] = elem
            self.num_of_elems += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Exception("Queue is empty")
        elem = self.data[self.front_ind]
        self.data[self.front_ind] = None
        self.front_ind = (self.front_ind + 1) % len(self.data)
        self.num_of_elems -= 1

        if self.is_empty():
            self.front_ind = None
        # As with dynamic arrays, we shrink the underlying array (by half) if we are using less than 1/4 of the capacity
        elif len(self) < len(self.data) // 4:
            self.resize(len(self.data) // 2)
        return elem

    # O(1) running time
    def first(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Exception("Queue is empty")
        return self.data[self.front_ind]

    def que_rear(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            print("Queue is empty")
        print("Rear item is",  self.data[self.rear])

    # Resizing takes time O(n) where n is the number of elements in the queue
    def resize(self, new_capacity):
        old_data = self.data
        self.data = [None] * new_capacity
        old_ind = self.front_ind

        for new_ind in range(self.num_of_elems):
            self.data[new_ind] = old_data[old_ind]
            old_ind = (old_ind + 1) % len(old_data)
        self.front_ind = 0
```

Comment: I'm not really sure I follow what you're asking here. The `data` member is an internal circular array that should not be printed--it's an implementation detail and this data structure could just as easily be refactored to use a linked list. Are you confused by the fact that the list is circular, so the rear index might be less than the front index?

Comment: Well I’m really asking what element is the rear index. Is it supposed to be the element most recently added. Or the element at the end of the list.

Comment: It looks to me like this `que_rear` method was added post-hoc. Is that correct? Again, it's testing an implementation detail. It's not permitted to access the last element in a queue structure, only the first. So as long as the queue first item is always correct (which it is because the pointer shifts just before enqueueing a new element), the output of this method is irrelevant. I can post an answer with a more thorough explanation if all my assumptions here are correct (i.e. you added `que_rear` to try to figure out how the class works and were confused by what it prints).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `que_rear` function seems to be added post-hoc in an attempt to understand how the internal [circular queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) operates. But notice that `self.rear` (the variable `que_rear` uses to determine what the "rear" is) is a meaningless garbage variable, in spite of its promising name. In the initializer, it's set to the internal array length and [never gets touched again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_store), so it's just pure luck if it prints out the rear or anything remotely related to the rear.

The true rear is actually the variable `back_ind`, which is computed on the spot whenever `enqueue` is called, which is the only time it matters what the back is. Typically, queue data structures don't permit access to the back or rear (if it did, that would make it a [deque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue), or double-ended queue), so all of this is irrelevant and implementation-specific from the perspective of the client (the code which is using the class to do a task as a [black box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)), without caring how it works).

Here's a function that gives you the actual rear. Unsurprisingly, it's pretty much a copy of part of `enqueue`:

```
def queue_rear(self):
    if self.is_empty():
        raise Exception("Queue is empty")

    back_ind = (self.front_ind + self.num_of_elems - 1) % len(self.data)
    return self.data[back_ind]
```

Also, I understand this class is likely for educational purposes, but I'm obliged to mention that in a real application, use [`collections.dequeue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) for all your queueing needs ([unless you need a synchronized queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717148/queue-queue-vs-collections-deque)).

Interestingly, CPython [doesn't use a circular array to implement the deque](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/762f93ff2efd6b7ef0177cad57939c0ab2002eac/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L33), but Java does in its [`ArrayDeque` class](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayDeque.java), which is worth a read.

Comment: Ok, now that makes more sense. And yes, I added the function to see what it would return to get a better understanding queues. Thank you so much