# Looping through Queue in Python without loosing elements

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through a Queue from the `queue`module in python, I dont want to empty the queue, I dont know how. This is my code.

```
from queue import Queue
q = Queue()
q.put(3)
q.put(5)
q.put(7)
for element in q:
    print(element)
```

How can I do this?
The error messange is:
`TypeError: 'Queue' object is not iterable`
I want to use Queue, because Im using it for BFS. I cant empty the Queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `q.queue`:

```
from queue import Queue

q = Queue()
q.put(3)
q.put(5)
q.put(7)

for element in q.queue:
    print(element)
```

**Output:**

```
3
5
7
```

Note you may want to consider using [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead.

Comment: You have solved my problem.

Comment: Why would I use collections.deque instead, whats the problem with queue.Queue()

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/717261/6328256, also `q.queue` is a deque anyway.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `queue` attribute is not documented, and is not intended to be used directly. A queue isn't designed to be iterated over: it provides constant-operations to inserting and deleting at one (not necessarily the same) end of the queue (and in the case of the `queue` module, thread safety).